# How do I validate parameters before assigning them?

Tags: java, validation

I want to check that my integer parameters for my grade variables are all valid (non-negative) before I assign them.  What would be the best way to code this?

I'm a Java beginner, and I'm trying to determine the most acceptable method to validate the grade parameters.

```
package com.example.android.StudentRecord;

// Name of the class
public class ReportCard {

    //Declare the private variables
    private long studentID;
    private int quarterYear;
    private String subject1;
    private int subject1Grade;
    private String subject2;
    private int subject2Grade;
    private String subject3;
    private int subject3Grade;


    //Use constructor to initialize all of the parameters of ReportCard
    public ReportCard(long studentID, int quarterYear,
                      String subject1, int subject1Grade,
                      String subject2, int subject2Grade,
                      String subject3, int subject3Grade) {
        this.studentID = studentID;
        this.quarterYear = quarterYear;
        this.subject1 = subject1;
        this.subject1Grade = subject1Grade;
        this.subject2=subject2;
        this.subject2Grade = subject2Grade;
        this.subject3=subject3;
        this.subject3Grade = subject3Grade;
    }


    //Use getter and setter methods to get the values and then set the values

    public long getStudentID()  {return studentID; }

    public void setStudentID(long ID) {
        studentID = ID;
    }

    public int getQuarterYear() {
        return quarterYear;
    }

    public void setQuarterYear(int qYear) {
        quarterYear = qYear;
    }

    public String getSubject1() {
        return subject1;
    }

    public void setSubject1(String subject) {
        subject1 = subject;
    }

    public int getSubject1Grade() {
        return subject1Grade;
    }

    public void setSubject1Grade(int grade) {
        subject1Grade = grade;
    }

    public String getSubject2() {
        return subject2;
    }

    public void setSubject2(String subject) {
        subject2 = subject;
    }

    public int getSubject2Grade() {
        return subject2Grade;
    }

    public void setSubject2Grade(int grade) {
        subject2Grade = grade;
    }

    public String getSubject3() {
        return subject3;
    }

    public void setSubject3(String subject) {
        subject3 = subject;
    }

    public int getSubject3Grade() {
        return subject3Grade;
    }

    public void setSubject3Grade(int grade) {
        subject3Grade = grade;
    }


    //Returns the string representation of the {@link ReportCard} object.

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ReportCard{" +
                "StudentID='" + studentID + '\'' +
                ", QuarterYear='" + quarterYear + '\'' +
                ", " + subject1 + ": " + subject1Grade + '\'' +
                ", " + subject2 + ": " + subject2Grade + '\'' +
                ", " + subject3 + ": " + subject3Grade;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to make sure that it's actually necessary to validate the parameters here, or if it should be validated at the user input layer.

If you believe it's necessary, throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if a parameter is invalid.

```
if (subject1Grade < 0 || subject2Grade < 0 || subject3Grade < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Grades must not be negative");
}
```

Or if you would rather silently ignore invalid parameters, give a default value.

```
this.subject1Grade = Math.max(0, subject1Grade);
this.subject2Grade = Math.max(0, subject2Grade);
this.subject3Grade = Math.max(0, subject3Grade);
```